# How should one interpret the religion lens?

Tags: civilization-6

See below image. This is the lens that is shown with missionaries, etc.

One would think that the numbered overlay shows the number of citizens in the city adhering to each religion. Aachen thus has 0 Confucian citizens (green) and 6 Absurdism citizens (blue - my religion). However, this doesn't line up with the City Details dialogue where it shows 0 for Confucianism but doesn't list Absurdism at all.

That's only the case for Aachen, which also happens to be the only city with a Holy Site. Aachen is also the site where I used a Great Prophet to found the religion. For the other two cities, the Religion view lines up with City Details. So perhaps this part is just a bug in City Details?

One thing that is clear: The circles are just a graphical representation of the proportion of citizens for each faith. At first, I thought it might be a progress indicator, but it isn't.

One related issue: Sometimes when I spread faith with a missionary, the citizen count doesn't move at all. For example, I spread on Berlin but it stayed at 3. Is this a rounding error or does spreading faith not always work?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The city detail for religion does seem to be bugged as it really often does not show the current primary religion's numbers. So it will only list the number of citizens of religions OTHER than the city's primary religion, if it has one.

You are right about the circles, it shows the % of every religion.

As for spreading faith, it's not that it didn't work, but every time you spread faith, you give the city a certain amount of religion points or pressure. The game does not indicate anywhere how much pressure/points is needed for the next citizen or how much every religions have or anything really, so it's really hard to tell what is actually going on. It just means your spread wasn't enough to convert another full citizen. Converting citizens gets harder and harder if most of them are already following a religion.

Lastly, the --> next to Confucianism in Magdeburg shows that Confucianism is on the rise in that city most probably because of pressure from nearby cities following Confucianism. Every city following a religion gives off some pressure to nearby cities for that same religion (similar to how it worked in Civ V), this pressure can be enhanced through beliefs and I am almost certain the Holy City gives off more pressure than others. Again I am not sure how most of this works as the game explains very little, but the more citizens follow a certain religion, the less likely the pressure or religious spreads seem to affect that city for that particular religion.

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful. Some other things that are unclear: 1) Is pressure from a city influenced by the number (and/or %) of citizens in a city that follow a religion, or is it just binary (the city follows the religion or it doesn't). 2) Can a minority religion in a city exert any pressure, 3) Do trade routes exert any pressure, 4) Do religious buildings contribute to pressure.

Comment: For 1) and 2) I believe it is binary and I don't think trades routes give off any pressure, but I am not sure about any of these, sadly